# Filtering specific files in a folder based on a list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a folder with a lot of files. These files are saved by individual names. I want to extract the files based on a list of names. Finally these extracted files should be saved in a new folder.

I have imported all the files in the specific folder

```
list_files = [file[0] for file in list_files]
```

Below is the list of files in the folder

```
['C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Jack.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Bill.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Cort.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Niel.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Van.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Dick.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Nick.xlsx']
```

Next from a data frame I have created a list with the specific names I want to filter

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pow, col
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ('a', 2016,'Jack'),
    ('a', 2017,'Bill'),
    ('a', 2018,'Dat'),
  ('a', 2015,'Jane'),
  ('b', 2016,'Cort'),
    ('b', 2017,'Nick'),
    ('b', 2018,'Lam'),
  ('b', 2015,'Jane')

]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B","C"])

name_list = list(df.select('C').toPandas()['C'])
name_list
```

I want to filter these files from the list and save these files in a new location. Extracted files should be the below list

```
['C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Jack.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Bill.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Cort.xlsx',
C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Nick.xlsx']
```

This list of files should be saved in a new location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with the following function:

```
import re 

def filter_list(string, substr): 
    return [st for st in string if any(sub in st for sub in substr)] 

ls_1 = ['C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Jack.xlsx',
        'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Bill.xlsx',
        'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Cort.xlsx',
        'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Niel.xlsx',
        'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Van.xlsx',
        'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Dick.xlsx',
        'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Nick.xlsx']
ls_2 = ["Jack", "Bill", "Cort", "Nick"]

filter_list(ls_1, ls_2)
# ['C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Jack.xlsx', 
# 'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Bill.xlsx', 
# 'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Cort.xlsx', 
# 'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Nick.xlsx']
```

If you want to save them to another location, now that you have the list of the files you want to save, you can just move them using [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) function.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear on your exact requirement, Do you just want files with matching names to be kept in a separate list?
If the requirement is that then regex can just be used to match names and get a new list.

```
import re
#your filenames
filenames=['C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Jack.xlsx',
'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Bill.xlsx',
'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Cort.xlsx',
'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Niel.xlsx',
'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Van.xlsx',
'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Dick.xlsx',
'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Nick.xlsx']
#your names
data = [
    ('a', 2016,'Jack'),
    ('a', 2017,'Bill'),
    ('a', 2018,'Dat'),
  ('a', 2015,'Jane'),
  ('b', 2016,'Cort'),
    ('b', 2017,'Nick'),
    ('b', 2018,'Lam'),
  ('b', 2015,'Jane')
]
#matching names
result=[]

for i in filenames:
    name=re.findall("C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_(.*).xlsx",i)[0]
    if name in [i[2] for i in data]:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```

The result I got:

```
['C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Jack.xlsx', 'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Bill.xlsx', 'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Cort.xlsx', 'C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Nick.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from good logic provided by @pissall and @Axxelerated , You can also try with `inner join` of pyspark between filename extracted names and another name dataframe

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

data = [
    ('a', 2016, 'Jack'),
    ('a', 2017, 'Bill'),
    ('a', 2018, 'Dat'),
    ('a', 2015, 'Jane'),
    ('b', 2016, 'Cort'),
    ('b', 2017, 'Nick'),
    ('b', 2018, 'Lam'),
    ('b', 2015, 'Jane')

]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B", "C"])
df1.show()

df = spark.createDataFrame([('C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Jack.xlsx',),
                            ('C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Bill.xlsx',),
                            ('C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Cort.xlsx',),
                            ('C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Niel.xlsx',),
                            ('C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Van.xlsx',),
                            ('C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Dick.xlsx',),
                            ('C:/A/results/fie_d_t_group_Nick.xlsx',)],['filename'])

df.show(truncate=False)

df2 = df.withColumn('name', F.regexp_extract(df.filename, '.*_(\w+).xlsx', 1))

df2.show()

df2.join(df1, df1.C == df2.name, "inner").drop('name', 'A', 'B', 'C').show(truncate=False)
```